# React Testing Library Select Dropdown Option isn't selecting anything

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have the following failing test:

```
import React from "react";
import { fireEvent, render } from "@testing-library/react";
import selectEvent from "react-select-event";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";

// test i'm trying to run
test("Can Select Item", async () => {
  const user = userEvent.setup();
  
  const screen = render(
    <select data-testid={"test"}>
      <option value="1" data-testid={"Hey"}>
        Hey
      </option>
      <option value="2">There</option>
    </select>
  );
  
  await user.selectOptions(screen.getByTestId("test"), "Hey");
  expect(screen.getByTestId("Hey").hasAttribute("selected")).toBeTruthy();
});
```

I can replace the trigger with this and it also fails:

```
fireEvent.select(screen.getByTestId("test"), { target: { value: "1" } });
expect(screen.getByTestId("Hey").hasAttribute("selected")).toBeTruthy();
```

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "test-jest",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

The error message I'm getting is:

```
SelectField Test > Can Select Item
-----
Error: expect(received).toBeTruthy()

Received: false Jest
```

...which isn't very helpful

If I run the following:

```
const result = fireEvent.select(screen.getByTestId("test"), {
  target: { value: "1" },
});
expect(result).toBeUndefined();
```

this test passes.  The result *should* be true, not undefined.

I'm using the following npx and npm and node:

```
❯ nvm -v
1.1.11

❯ npx -v
6.14.15

❯ npm -v
6.14.15

❯ node
Welcome to Node.js v14.18.3.
```

I was originally trying to get this to work with some Chakra code and thought that it was something wrong with the Chakra library.  But then I tried writing this sample code, and I got the same issues as before.  If I compare the `screen.getByTestId("test").innerHTML` before and after everything is exactly the same.  I've tried implementing the test using the `react-select-event` library as well, with no luck.  What am I doing wrong here?  Is there a version issue?  Could it be something else?

Comment: Please add the exact error/failure message to your question

Comment: @BrianThompson I'm not getting anything useful, just 
```
SelectField Test > Can Select Item
-----
Error: expect(received).toBeTruthy()

Received: false Jest
```

Comment: although if i run 

const result = fireEvent.select(screen.getByTestId("test"), {
    target: { value: "1" },
  });
  expect(result).toBeUndefined();

This test passes which is weird because it should be returning true or fase.

Comment: I see that you edited out the part about debugging resulting in an infinite loop. Is that not happening anymore? I can't figure out what would cause this so the only suggestion I would have is to use the RTL debugging utility to get the HTML that was actually used and attach it to the question in hopes that there's some clues there

Comment: yea the infinite loop stopped, but i did end up solving the problem

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer that's working for me now.  This is what it looks like:

```
import React from "react";
import { fireEvent, render } from "@testing-library/react";

export interface KeyValuePair {
  value: string;
  selected: boolean;
}

it("should correctly set default option", () => {
  const { getByTestId, getAllByTestId } = render(
    <select data-testid={"select"}>
      <option>Test option selects</option>
      <option key={"1"} value="1" data-testid={"select-option"}>
        Hey
      </option>
      <option key={"2"} value="2" data-testid={"select-option"}>
        There
      </option>
    </select>
  );
  fireEvent.select(getByTestId("select"), { target: { value: "1" } });
  let options = getAllByTestId("select-option") as HTMLOptionElement[];
  const values = options
    .map(
      (e) =>
        ({
          value: e.value as string,
          selected: e.selected as boolean,
        } as KeyValuePair)
    )
    .filter((x) => x.selected);
  expect(values).toHaveLength(1);
  expect(values[0].value).toBe("1");
});
```